# How to change to display format of datetime received from a database in java

Tags: java, sql, swing, date

I use this code to change util to sql, but the record happens with seconds and another value after

```
String insertAttendence = null;
insertAttendence = "INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE (PRSN_ID,DATE,ARRIVAL,DEPART,DATE_ARRIVAL_FROM,DATE_DEPARTURE_TO) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement psAttendence = null;

psAttendence = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertAttendence);
psAttendence.setInt(1, personIdForGraphics.intValue());
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(dates.get(i).getTime());               
psAttendence.setDate(2, sqlDate);
```

In the database it is saved as follows 2019-07-26 11: 53: 18.0, I want it to be saved so 2019-07-26 11:53:18, how to change it?

Comment: what type is the column in the database ? Columns of type Date or DateTime are not stored in any format at all, but as a numeric value. It is you software that shows it like that. Unless you made the mistake to store datetime values in a varchar column of course

Comment: Datetime type in datebase

Comment: then there is no format in your database. DateTime columns are stored as numeric values. It is the software you use to show the values that provides the format, it is there that you have to change the format, not in the database

Comment: How to make changes in software?

Comment: depends on which software. Did you wrote it ? then you can change it, else you have to contact the vendor where you bought it.

Comment: I myself wrote the code for me, I provided the code for java

Comment: I dont know java so im sorry I cant help you any further with this. Maybe you can change your question and ask how to change to display format of datetime received from a database in java

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `java.sql.Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). If you need to display the value to the user in a specific format, use a `DateTimeFormatter`. Don’t worry about the format in your database or inside your program.

Comment: You’ve got a basic problem. The long value you get from `dates.get(i).getTime()` denotes a specific moment (instant) in time that you would probably like to save, but a database datatype of `datetime` doesn’t because it does not include time zone. If you can, change the datatype in the database to `timestamp with time zone` to solve.

Comment: Your title says you want to change the display format after retrieval from your database. Your question text says you want your datatime saved in a specific format. Aren’t they two quite different things? Which of them fo you want? (I answered the second.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You don’t want to

You don’t want the `datetime` in your database to have a specific format. Good practice in all but the simplest throw-away programs is to keep your user interface apart from your data model. The value of the `datetime` belongs in your model, so keep your `datetime` there and never let the user see it directly. When you adhere to this, it will never matter which format the `datetime` has got in the database. Whenever the user should see the date, format it into a `String` and show the string to the user. Similarly if you need a specific format for exchange with another system, format the datetime into a string for that purpose. If the user needs to enter a date and/or time, either accept a string or use a date picker or time picker.

### You cannot

As @GuidoG has already said in comments, a datetime is stored in the database in some internal format that we don’t know and shouldn’t care about. It certainly isn’t the `2019-07-26 11: 53: 18.0` that you reported. You may have seen that in some query tool or as a result of retrieving the datetime as a string from your database, I don’t know. It may also be that you can configure your query tool to show you a different format. You can think of the `datetime` in the database as a date and time of day, nothing more, nothing less.

In short “format” applies only to the string representations of datetimes, not to the datetimes themselves.

### java.time and JDBC 4.2

The `java.sql.Date` class that you were using is poorly designed and long outdated. Also your JDBC driver should treat it as a date without time of day, and most JDBC drivers do (so it’s a bit weird how you got your code to store `2019-07-26 11: 53: 18.0` *with* non-zero time of day).

Assuming that you want to store a point in time (a timestamp), change your database column to datatype `timestamp with time zone` and then store an `OffsetDateTime` into it. I am assuming that `dates.get(i).getTime()` gives you the milliseconds since the epoch.

```
    OffsetDateTime dateTimeToSave = Instant.ofEpochMilli(dates.get(i).getTime())
            .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    psAttendence.setObject(2, dateTimeToSave);
```

If you cannot change the datatype, you may store a `LocalDateTime` into your database column using `psAttendence.setObject` in the same way, but you will have to make sure yourself that you get a `LocalDateTime` in the right time zone since the object itself carries neither time zone nor offset. UTC is recommended.

**Tutorial link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


      Date date = new Date();  
      SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD hh:mm");  
      String strDate= formatter.format(date);  
      System.out.println(strDate); 


}
```

}

Comment: you can change the format as per your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. No matter which way I read the question I can’t really see that you are answering it, though. If you just read the question differently from how I read it, it’s probably advantageous to make clear in your answer how you understood it.